# How to include regexp in lexical rascal structure?

Tags: rascal

i'm trying improve java18 lexical structure by recognize big numbers like 1_111_111.

i tried:

```
lexical DeciNumeral = 
"0"
| \b([1-9](\d{0,2}))(_\d{3,3})*\b;
```

Thanks to @davy and @jurgenv. I managed to solve my problem with this code

```
lexical DeciNumeral =
"0"
| [1-9]
| [1-9] [0-9 _]* [0-9];
```

Comment: i managed todo a valid regexp without macros utilizing |[1-9] [0-9]? [0-9]? ("_" [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] )* instead the first one, but now i get ambguity issues.

Comment: If you need longest match behavior to avoid ambiguity you can use `[1-9] [0-9]? [0-9]? ("_" [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] )* !>> [0-9]` for example. The `!>> [0-9]` is a follow constraints saying the list may not be accepted if another 0-9 is on the lookahead.

Comment: The `>` sign has no effect here. might as well replace it with `|`

Comment: code updated. thx for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lexicals are not regular expressions](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/SyntaxDefinition.html). They are just normal non-terminals without interleaved layout.
There are productions in a nonterminal that support a subset of regular expressions. Read more about it here: [Symbol](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/Symbol/Symbol.html).

your code sample could be:

```
lexical DeciNumeral = {[0-9]+ !>> [0-9] "_"}+;
```

which is one or more groups of numbers, possible seperated by underscores.

ps: Nice that you are extending the Java 1.5 grammar, if possible, share your results!

Comment: or why not `lexical DeciNumeral = [0-9\_]+;`

Comment: not sure if `_42_42` is allowed, was going for a slightly smaller language that was still close to the regexp in the question (with the `[0-9]` as first char).

Comment: 0 cannot to be the first char in this notation and _ comports like "." for great number.

Comment: nevermind, i just saw the documentation. the only constraints are: "0" cannot to be the first char and "_" cannot to be last one